# How to put this Query into Linq (C#)?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, t-sql, razor

I'm able to do:

```
 var codeStation = from Code in ent.Role 
                   where Code.Code.StartsWith("S_") 
                   select Code;
```

(ent: being my Entity for my Database)

That gives me :

```
S_ANC
S_ATL
S_BNA
S_BOS
S_BRU
S_CLT
..... 
S_YXE
S_YXY
S_YYC
S_YYG
S_YYT
S_YYZ
```

**How can I accomplish the equivalent of the following SQL query?**

```
SELECT Substring(Codes,3,6)   
FROM Role
WHERE Codes LIKE 'S%'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var codeStation = from Code in ent.Role 
                  where Code.Code.StartsWith("S_") 
                  select RoleName.Substring(3,6);
```

Comment: I can't because I need the var to be a IQueryable<MyObject> and not IQueryable<string>.

Answer (score 1):

Your LINQ query can `select` any legal C# expression you want, including method calls on the field names. So, you can do something like this:

```
var codeStation = from Code in ent.Role 
                  where Code.Code.StartsWith("S_") 
                  select Code.RoleName.SubString(3,6);
```

Comment: I can't because I need the var to be a IQueryable<MyObject> and not IQueryable<string>.